# Android Studio Kotlin Refrofit - Distincby using

Tags: android, sql-server, kotlin

When I send the same multiple data over [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouy4W.png)database, I want to separate them by size in the product details section. The same product name and product code comes line by line, but the only difference is the size and color codes. How can I separate the colors and sizes of the products that come with the same product name and code in the product detail section?

I heard about its distinctBy feature, can it work

My data;

Comment: share the code, models, what u did so far etc.

Comment: Make it more explanatory by adding the code snippets.